# Cosmos DB Querying DateTime in LINQ works when using ToList() but not when IQueryable

Tags: c#, azure, linq, json.net, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to get all records that have start dates that are within a specific range. My query only returns results when using `ToList()`.

My Class Example:

```cs
public class TestEvent
{

}

public class TestEvent : EntityBase
{
    public TestEvent()
    {

    }


    [JsonProperty("dates")]
    public List<DateRange> Dates
    {
        get;set;
    }
}

public class DateRange
{
    [JsonProperty("startDate")]
    public DateTime StartDate
    {
        get; set;
    }

    [JsonProperty("endDate")]
    public DateTime EndDate
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

My code to retrieve the records:

```cs
var pQuery = Entities<TestEvent>().Where(x => x.Dates.Any(d => d.StartDate < DateTime.Now));

foreach (var pEvent in pQuery)
{
    Page.Response.Write(pEvent.Name + "<br/>");

    foreach (DateRange pRange in pEvent.Dates)
    {
        Page.Response.Write(pRange.StartDate + "<br/>");
    }
}
```

Code only returns values when `ToList()` is called on the datasource first...

**This line works:**

```cs
var pQuery = Entities<TestEvent>()
    .ToList() // Note .ToList()
    .Where(x => x.Dates.Any(d => d.StartDate < DateTime.Now));
```

**and this one does not:**

```cs
var pQuery = Entities<TestEvent>()
    // Note no .ToList()
    .Where(x => x.Dates.Any(d => d.StartDate < DateTime.Now));
```

Can anyone help me understand why the second call does not produce any results? and maybe help me get this to work without having to load all the records first with `ToList()`?
According to Microsoft, it should. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/11503872-support-linq-any-or-where-for-child-object-collect

The first call (`ToList()`) loads them all into memory first and works but it would not be good for production.

I am using Cosmos V3 most recent version.
There is data in the collection. (Loads properly when I exclude the `where` statement)

Here is the output from the query `ToString()`:

> {"query":"SELECT VALUE root FROM root JOIN (SELECT VALUE EXISTS(SELECT VALUE d0 FROM root JOIN d0 IN root[\"dates\"] WHERE (d0[\"startDate\"] < \"2019-12-20T16:06:14.197226-06:00\") ) ) AS v0 WHERE v0 "}

I also tried this in cosmos data explorer with no results and no errors:

> JOIN (SELECT VALUE EXISTS(SELECT VALUE d0 FROM c JOIN d0 IN c["dates"] WHERE ((d0["startDate"] >= "2019-12-20T16:25:44.9759932-06:00") AND (d0["endDate"] > "2019-12-20T16:25:44.9759932-06:00")) ) ) AS v0 WHERE v0

Comment: `var pQuery` is of type IQueryable and they are not executed when they are created.

Comment: You can use EagerLoading 
`var pQuery = Entities().Include(x => x.Dates.Any(d => d.StartDate < DateTime.Now));`

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? Do you get wrong results or an error? What error to you get?

Comment: I get no errors and no results

Comment: Clint, are you saying that ToList() is not an issue in this particular case?

Comment: ToList() will execeute SQL queries upfront to populate the list, which is a performance penalty if you have to retrieve a large set of records and queries

Comment: @user2638032 what is surprising is when you do not get any errors or results without ToList();

Comment: Clint, I agree. Also any other 'Where' query on the Dates Property I execute returns no results unless I have ToList() first. almost like the time when i was getting no records because of the CamelCase Linq issue that forced me to use JsonProperty on all my fields.

Comment: If you want to alleviate the overhead of converting to ToList, you can consider doing explicit loading
var pQuery = Entities().Where(x => x.Dates.Any(d => d.StartDate < DateTime.Now)).Load();

Comment: What si `Entities<TestEvent>()` IQueriable?

Comment: Train, it is a call to a method: CosmosContainer.GetItemLinqQueryable<T>(true, null, pOptions);

Comment: If you get no results then there's ether a bug in Cosmos that does not emit the right SQL or the time on the server is different that the local time which yields different results.

Comment: I notice you have 2 different types Entities<TestEvent>() & Entities<TestEventBase>(). And you're applying ToList to the former

Comment: D Stanley. good call but I tried it with my own pStart variable too.

Comment: D Stanley Is there a way to see the SQL generated by Cosmos for this Query??

Comment: Clint, TestEventBase is a typo.  i fixed it.

Comment: @user2638032: I guess you can use `var doc = pquery.AsDocumentQuery().ToString()` to see queries that will be executed against your db

Comment: @user2638032, its a good idea to continue the discussion on a separate chat, please initiate one and add me

Comment: My reputation is too low to chat... Thanks Clint

Comment: Clint is there another way we could talk?? willing to pay for help

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204633/cosmodb-query chat room

Comment: Here is the output from the query: {"query":"SELECT VALUE root FROM root JOIN (SELECT VALUE EXISTS(SELECT VALUE d0 FROM root JOIN d0 IN root[\"dates\"] WHERE (d0[\"startDate\"] < \"2019-12-20T16:06:14.197226-06:00\") ) ) AS v0 WHERE v0 "}

Comment: Train, Thanks but so will not let me communicate with you because I don't have a 20 reputation.

Comment: [`DateTime.Now`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.now?view=netframework-4.8) is not a field or constant, it's a property that returns the current date and time on your local system -- i.e. it's constantly changing.  Perhaps an expression containing it can't be evaluated on the server side via `IQueryable`.  Instead, try assigning the value to a local variable `var now = DateTime.Now` and use that in your query, e.g. `Entities<TestEvent>().Where(x => x.Dates.Any(d => d.StartDate < now));`